# Add activex control combo box using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would want to add a combobox from ActiveX Control using VBA. Whenever I execute the code below, I am able to generate the combo box however, I keep getting a message that says "Can't enter break mode at this time". Why does this happen and how can I avoid this message from appearing?

Below is the code that i used.

```
Sheets("Data Transfer").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
    , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=265, Top:=465, Width:=108.125, Height:= _
    30).Select
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. The message is usually associated with break points set in the code, most often for purposes of debugging. Do you have such break points? Another reason I imagine is your use of `Select`. You shouldn't select anything in your code and most likely you shouldn't select the new combo box, either. If your code is littered with `Select` one of these might try to cause an illegal break. Use the `Range` object instead of the `Selection` object throughout your code.

Comment: @Variatus I did not have any break points . I tried another version without  select and i still got the same result. 
`Sheets("Data Transfer").OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CommandButton.1", _
    Left:=10, Top:=10, Height:=20, Width:=100`

Comment: @Variatus This issue has been solved but i do not understand why. This is solved when i run the entire program all at once. But when i press F8 to run the program it then gives me this problem. may i know why is this so?

Comment: Basically, the creation of the combo box is a process involving several programmatic steps, such as creating the OLEobject in memory, connecting it to the sheet, giving it a visible shape and assigning dimensions to that shape. VBA doesn't support the interruption of this process. As you step through the code VBA somehow gets the notion that you try to run a part of that process and break in the middle of it. If this isn't what you are trying to do it would look like a bug. However, since I couldn't reproduce the error your Excel app appears different from mine. Try "repairing" it.